# Connected components and real continuous functions

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\cup X_i$ be a topological space, where $X_i$s are the connected components of $X$, if $f$ is a real value function on $X$ such that its restrictions to $X_i$s are continuous. Is $f$ continuous on $X$?

Answer (score 7):

Hint: If this were true, every real function on $\mathbb{Q}$ would be continuous.

---

Explanation: $\mathbb{Q}$ is totally disconnected, meaning every connected component is a singleton. Every function on a singleton is continuous. Therefore, assuming the "proposition" stated is true, it would follow that any real function defined on $\mathbb{Q}$ is continuous. But this is clearly not true. Take $\chi_{\mathbb{Q_{\geq 0}}}$ for example (the indicator function).

As a special observation, if there are **FINITELY MANY** connected components, it is true. This follows because since every connected component is closed, finitely many connected components imply that they are also open. Therefore, they form an open covering of the space.

Comment: I upvoted your answer for my mistake :) But I don't know who downvoted your answer.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Making mistakes is normal. Mathematics is beautiful partly due to this. Leaving a downvote with no explanation though, in my opinion, is annoying. Although this is unfortunately not a consensus on the community.

It is annoying partly because I COULD have made a mistake. And then I would not know, because the person downvoted and never commented anything. But I digress.

Comment: It’s a shame about the downvote; the hint was excellent. On the plus side, it stimulated you to add the last paragraph, which nicely rounds out the answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much for the kind words. : )

Comment: My bad, I never thought carefully about your hint. Downvote retracted.