# Properties of the trace operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am using the book of Evans and try to understand the trace operator. I have the following question:

Let $u \in H^1(U)$ with $Du = 0$ and $Tu = 0$. Then (because of $Du = 0$) I know that $u$ must be constant on each connected component of $U$. But if $u \in H^1(U) \cap C(\overline{U})$, we have $Tu = u \vert_{\partial U}$. Can I use this (or something else) to conclude that $u = 0$?

Answer (score 2):

If $Tu=0$ then $u \in H^1_0(U)$ and you have the Poincare inequality

$$\|u\|_{L^2(U)} \leq  C\|Du\|_{L^2(U)},$$

for any open and bounded $U$ (not necessarily connected). So if $Du=0$ and $Tu=0$ then $u=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $Du=0$, it follows $u=$ constant on each connected component, hence $u$ is continuous on each component, thus the trace operator yields the values of $u$ on the boundary, hence $u=0$.

In pde analysis, one often works with domains $U$ that are open and connected sets. So you do not need to worry too much about connected components.

Comment: I only see that $u$ is piecewise continuous on each connected component.

Comment: Well, if you piecewise define independent continuous functions on the connected components, then their union will be *continuous*, since each connected component is open.

Comment: @Berci I am sorry, but I do not understand why the union is continuous. I always have a picture in mind of two connected components where the function $u$ takes two different constant values. Why is there no jump between these two values?

Comment: @Berci To conclude that the connected components are open, we need to know that there are only finitely many of them. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931038/connected-components-and-real-continuous-functions